# grouping elements in a list in haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I want to transform a list from `[1,26,3,94,51,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,73,29,19,90,76,87,1]`

to `[[1],[26,3],[94,51,6],[7,8,9,10],[11,12,73,29,19]]` and so on till end in haskell. (I'm trying to group the elements in increasing order of length of sub list)

I am new to haskell please help me out

Comment: What is the grouping criterion? Why are `[26,3]` grouped together? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own recursively function that receives a list and returns a list of list, first we need to [take](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/take_f.html) n elements from the list, for that we call `take n xs`, afterwards we need to cons the element with the rest of the elements for this we need to call `mySplit n+1` and drop the element that we incorporated to list, so we only need to `call drop n xs` [drop](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/drop_f.html).

```
mySplit :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
mySplit n [] = []
mySplit n xs = (take n xs):(mySplit (n + 1) (drop n xs))

ghci> mySplit 1 [1,26,3,94,51,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,73,29,19,90,76,87,1]
[[1],[26,3],[94,51,6],[7,8,9,10],[11,12,73,29,19],[90,76,87,1]]
```

Comment: Thank You. Is there any inbuilt function to do the same?

Comment: Yes, you can use a foldr with a lambda.

Comment: [`splitAt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:splitAt) would make this code a bit more efficient, so that you don't have to iterate the list twice with `take` and `drop`.